# emacs: reinstall package after installation error

Tags: package, elpy

I'm new to Emacs. I needed to install the `elpy` package for python (as described [here](http://chillaranand.github.io/emacs-py-ide/)), but as I forgot to install one python package with `pip`, the installation with `M-x package-install RET elpy` failed.

I installed the missing python package, but I can't restart the installation of elpy on emacs. It remembers the previous error and won't try reinstalling.

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to delete elpy package from `M-x list-packages`? You can do it by pressing `d` on the elpy package, and then pressing `yes` to confirm the action. If you already did that, you can go to `~/.emacs.d` and delete the elpy folder created when you installed it. Hope this help you.